# Display weekly schedule with jQuery calendar plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery calendar plugin FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to build a 7day calendar.  Like this example from here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/views/basicWeek/ the week starts from Sunday and display past schedules.  How do I adjust this so that the week starts from Today and displays schedule from Today on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [firstDay](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/firstDay/) property

```
firstDay: new Date().getDay(),
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dcFEC/)